# MySQL rebuild after Corrupt ibdata1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I have a MySQL server that serves a couple of databases including a Magento e-commerce store.

We have been suffering with corruption in the ibdata1 file for a while, but it has now reached a critical point.

The only database that uses innodb tables is the Magento webstore back-end.

I have an up to date SQL extract of the entire magento database. I thought that I could shut down MySQL, rename the ib* files, restart MySQL and re-create the database from the SQL file - however I am having a major problem restarting MySQL after renaming the ib* files.

I keep getting 'cannot connect to mysql ..... mysql.sock'.

It appears as though the ib* files are all re-created as I would expect, but I can't restart and then connect to the sever...

Any ideas??

#### EDIT

Have already tried all values of `innodb_force_recovery`. Error log shows various issues including

```
difficult to find free blocks from the buffer pool
```

and now also

```
InnoDB: Error: page 131073 log sequence number 17 3671003941
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 17 3670939210.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files
```

Answer (score 3):

When referring to `ib*` files, are you also referring to the `ib_log` files? They also need to be removed when you remove the `ibdata*` files. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql that might be of some help.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to all files that are prefixed with ib - ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. All have been renamed and all are being re-created, but I still cannot connect to MySQL